# Powershell calculation not returning value

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm trying to do a foreach loop to work through a csv file, nothing overly complex (or so i thought), however I'm not able to get the correct values back.

When I input the csv with the values below (which are in MB), I'd like to convert to gb, showing the comma for gb's.

CSV

```
DB1 10
DB2 1200
db3 50
db4 900
```

The values i get are

```
DB1 0
DB2 1
db3 0
db4 0
```

The script I have is

```bsh
Import-Csv "c:\temp\sql.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $db = $_.Name
    $size = $_.Size

    $newsize = $size/1000

    Write-Host "database $db is $newsize gb"  | Out-File "C:\temp\sql.txt" -Append
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'm vastly surprised that you get ANYTHING from that code. [*grin*] i have never been able to get `Write-Host` to send ANYTHING to the pipeline. try the more standard method of building a string and sending that to your output file with `Add-Content` ... and don't use `Write-Host` for anything other than screen output ... that is what the `-Host` part means. [*grin*]

Comment: @AdminOfThings still returning the same values with ` $newsize = [double]($size/1000)` I also tried casting to 2 decimal spaces using `[math]::Round($newsize,2)` but no joy

Comment: @Thomas thanks, thats worked a treat, please add it as an answer :)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I notice you *[grin]* alot.

Comment: @RoadRunner - i am naturally grumpy & mean spirited, so i try to counter that with positive emotions ... and i am also quite hard-of-seeing, so i spell out the emoticons instead of using the shorter versions. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I think its a good idea for everyone to *grin* more :-)

Comment: we are about to get nagged to not do "visiting" ... so this is my final [*grin*] in this comment series ...

Comment: Lee_Daily, as for 'i have never been able to get Write-Host to send ANYTHING to the pipeline', it's becasue it doesn't, ever.
This, that pipe is just being ignored and sending the Write-Host to the screen not to the file
Write-Host "hello world" | Out-File -FilePath 'd:\temp\SomeStuff.txt'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp\SomeStuff.txt'
Get-Content -Path 'd:\temp\SomeStuff.txt' --- so you are not missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type problem. `$size` is of type `int` and therefore `$size/1000` will be an integer division. You can cast the variable to `double` to force a floating point division:

```
Import-Csv "c:\temp\sql.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $db = $_.Name
    $size = $_.Size

    $newsize = ([double]$size)/1KB

    "database $db is $([math]::Round($newsize,2)) GB" | Out-File "C:\temp\sql.txt" -Append
}
```